# Is it possible to set the language and locale to different values?

Tags: settings, languages, localization

I'd like to have all the text displayed in English (US), but use the Polish (Poland) formatting for numbers, dates etc. On a desktop Linux system, I'd set LANG to pl_PL and LC_MESSAGES to en_US. Is there a way to so on Android? I see only combined language+locale setting. Note: I am not asking about the keyboard, I know can set it to use a language different from the language+locale setting without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've set my phone to English (United States), but then I also customized Date & Time to use Italian format (DD/MM/YYYY). Numbers don't seem to be customizable, plus some apps ignore Date & Time settings and use the ones from the main language, or allow to specify a format.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the date and time format in the settings (system section) -> Date & Time.