# Is it possible to use another system language than the one defined by country

Tags: cyanogenmod, localization

I'd like to use my phone (CM 11, rooted) in English. The only problem I have is that this means that the contacts app doesn't sort names that begins with Å, Ä or Ö in their own separate section, they're shown within the A and O section. I thought that for example setting  locale to en_FI with MoreLocale 2 would solve the problem, but it doesn't. For example, Åsa is still shown between Arne and Atte.

Google hasn't helped, neither did I find answers here. [Is it possible to set the language and locale to different values?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/is-it-possible-to-set-the-language-and-locale-to-different-values) sounded right but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I have yet to manage this. I have mine set to "English Ireland" but it still has major issues sorting a name like Áine and then to make it worse, each appliction seems to have its own internal method for doing this. Áine is first on my contact list, but last on Facebook for example.

Answer (score 1):

Go to system setting and language & input.

(I also have CM11 but in BAM rom which includes many other roms)

Comment: And then what? This is what I have done, but there is no separation between language and country preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that, but you need to write your own logic to sort the names.

Considering plain standard English, the sorting is done using ASCII/Unicode values, and a-z and A-Z come in a sequence, where as the other alphabets like Å, Ä or Ö come later.

So when you use apps that are not specifically targetted for anything other than standard english, you have the problem you are having right now.

Comment: This is not true. The applications can sort the names correctly if I choose Finnish or Swedish as system language. If Unicode is used then it would be sorted correctly even with English as UI language